# Dual-interface JavaCard on wafer with ECDSA (and I2C)

Tags: security, encryption, nfc, smartcards

I'm looking for a JavaCard model that supports dual-interface (ISO 7816+14443), with ECDSA acceleration and optionally I2C interface. Available in wafer for custom NFC antenna and flip-chipping. Do you have any recommendation or comparison resource for such products?

Thank you.

Mario.